# After "could not", is it "help but notice" or "help noticing"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, phrase-choice, negation

I have read and heard examples of both "could not help but notice" and "could not help noticing".

> Hello, penguins. I could not help
> **but notice** that you have a hat
> that magically brings things.
>
> — The Penguins of Madagascar: Happy King Julien Day! (2009)

Again,

> Well, I'm sorry to have to put
> this to you, but I could not help
> **noticing** that you were miming.
>
> — A Bit of Fry and Laurie: S02E01 (1990)

We hear and read both versions. Which one is grammatical—are they both? Please mention the nuance of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are perfectly grammatical and both are used when one feels very strongly compelled to do something and can't stop themselves doing something.

**can't help but**

> We cannot help but intervene here, before you throw your life away on drugs!

> My mom can't help but meddle in my love life, even though I'm 30 years old!

**can't help doing**

> She couldn’t help laughing when she saw it.

> I shouldn’t have said it but I couldn’t help myself.

I've heard the former more frequently, and I feel it's a more colloquial phrase.

In some cases, I would say one of the forms is more common. For example,

> I couldn’t help thinking he was asking for trouble.

[image]